# Basic Google Analytics Click Tracking and/or Overview

Tags: google-analytics

This is a **really basic** Google Analytics question.  Apologies in advance if it's not appropriate here, but I've had a lot of luck on Stack Overflow and this seems like the best Stack Exchange site for a question like this.

I'm trying to understand how Google Analytics goals work, or if they're the right feature to be using for my situation.  Most of the documentation I find online refers to the old version of the UI, not the new one.

I have a website, let's call is blog.example.com.  This website drives traffic to an ecommerce store, let's call that store.example2.com.  I want to get reports on which links from blog.example.com are being clicked through leading to store.example2.com.

How do you do this in Google analytics?  Are goals the right area to be looking?  Do I setup the goals on store.example2.com or blog.example.com?  Or both?  Is there any canonical user guide (free or paid) that covers how this works? I'm a competent programmer, but it's years since I dealt with conversion tracking on any serious level, and we've progressed well beyond my frozen caveman pixel tracking knowledge.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to generate an Event for every click that goes from `blog.example.com` to `store.example2.com` and [use it as goal](http://analytics.blogspot.it/2011/04/new-google-analytics-events-goals.html).

So in your analytics on `blog.example.com` you can see how many links are you forwarding to `store.example2.com`. You can see this in Event reports. You can the use this to setup your goals.

Another solution that is not involving events / goals is to filter the referrals in the store.example2.com analytics referral reports.
You have a glimpse on how many referrals do you have from `blog.example.com`. If you click on the referral `blog.example.com`, you'll se the links that are clicked in `store.example2.com`